# Function for ranking multiple unique values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, unique, ranking

I'm currently tweaking my text search queries to get the best possible results for given search terms. What I'm looking for is a ranking function that will boost the score only for new unique values within the searched field. It also should score exact hits better than just prefix hits. I was able to achieve the desired results with a bulky query, but was wondering if you could achieve similar results more elegant using a rank function. I'll give you an example:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES ('Kate Mat');
INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES ('Kate Kate Mate');
INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES ('Cat Mat');
```

Here is my bulky query with the search terms 'Kate' + 'Mat':

```
SELECT
  title,
  a1 + a2 + b1 + b2 AS score
FROM (
       SELECT
         title,
         CASE WHEN to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('kate:*')
           THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS a1,
         CASE WHEN to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('kate')
           THEN 0.5
         ELSE 0
         END AS a2,
         CASE WHEN to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('mat:*')
           THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS b1,
         CASE WHEN to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('mat')
           THEN 0.5
         ELSE 0
         END AS b2
       FROM book
     ) scoredProducts
ORDER BY score DESC;

#----------------------results-------------------------
title           score
Kate Mat        3        -- exact hit for both terms
Kate Kate Mate  2.5      -- exact hit for 'Kate'. prefix hit for 'Mat'
Cat Mat         1.5      -- exact hit for 'Mat'
```

This is actually the result order I want to see. The obvious problem with the query is that I need to adapt it for every additional search term. I would like a syntax something more like this:

```
SELECT
  title,
  ts_rank(to_tsvector('english', book.title), to_tsquery('kate:* | mat:*')) AS score
FROM book
ORDER BY score DESC;

#----------------------results-------------------------
title           score
Kate Kate Mate  0.0683918      -- prefix hits for both terms
Kate Mat        0.06079271     -- exact hit gets scored less
Cat Mat         0.030396355
```

Which sadly delivers not the order I want because it scores multiple same hits better than exact unique hits. Is it possible to write such a custom rank function?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your problem,
You can simplify your query using a few basic SQL keywords and an aggregate funtion in this way:

```
SELECT
  b.title,
  sum( case when to_tsvector('english' , title ) @@ to_tsquery(a.keyword)
            then a.score end ) AS score
  FROM book b
  cross join  ( 
     values
     ( 'kate:*', 1 ),
     ( 'kate', 0.5 ),
     ( 'mat:*', 1 ),
     ( 'mat', 0.5 )
) as a(keyword, score)
group by b.title
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

You still have to adapt this query for each new search term, but now it seems slighly easier.

Comment: Thats more compact alright, didn't know about join values. My goal would be to have a function that could take the search terms like 'kate mat ...' and just calculates the order with prioritizing unique and exact hits.